# javascript/jquery do in order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code for and audio tag of html

```
$("#STOP").click(function(){
    $("#soundContainer")[0].currentTime = 0;
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("soundContainer").pause();
        $("#pause").val("pause");
        $("#insert_here").text("None");
    },100);
});
```

without timeout, pause doesn't work 
I guess that pause finishes first and then currentTime is set 
so it starts playing from the beginning rather than to stop

So Is there any other solution to avoid timeout?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Pause or stop?

Comment: stop, but with current time setting to zero, because I have custom progress which increases with currentTime, so after stopping I need it to drop to 0.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
document.querySelector('#STOP').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('#soundContainer').pause();
    document.querySelector('#soundContainer').currentTime = 0;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4681syzu/